# TWILIO code not calling the second number

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have the following TWIMlet:

```
<?php if ($_REQUEST['Digits'] == '1') { ?>
    <Play>ConnectingSupport.wav</Play>
    <Dial callerId="15559998888" action="Call_in.php">
        <Number url="screen_for_machine.php">
        +1555XXXXXXX
        </Number>
        <Number url="screen_for_machine.php">
        +1555YYYYYYY
        </Number>
    </Dial>

<?php } elseif ($_REQUEST['Digits'] == '2') { ?>
    <Play>ConnectingAssociate.wav</Play>
    <Dial callerId="18889990000" action="Call_in.php">
        <Number url="screen_for_machine.php">
        +1555YYYYYYY
        </Number>
        <Number url="screen_for_machine.php">
        +1555XXXXXXX
        </Number>
    </Dial>
<?php } elseif ($_REQUEST['Digits'] == '3') { ?>
    <Play>leavemessage.wav</Play>
    <Record maxLength="180" action="recording.php" />
<?php } ?>
```

Everything works as intended except when caller keys in #2 on their phone, only 1555YYYYYYY is called.  Whereas if #1 is keyed in, both numbers (1555XXXXXXX and 1555YYYYYYYY) are called simultaneously as intended.

What am I missing?  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing obvious jumps out. Have you tried debugging by removing all of the attributes? `<Dial><Number>+1XXXXXXXXXX</Number><Number>+1XXXXXXXXXX</Number></Dial>`

Comment: If I remove them then no number gets called.  I tried flipping the numbers around just in case... same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code above, if one line goes straight to voicemail (i.e. cellphone with no reception), that's a pick up.  Hence the second line doesn't have a chance to ring yet.

The solution is to hold the call in a queue, then call each line and use 'voicemail' detection. [See details here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine)

More coding for me to do :) so long.